# Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, adb

I am trying to connect my HTC Wildfire and I was activated the (USB debugging) and connected it to pc but it was not recognized by Eclipse

And that error : Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

I reset adb but the same error occurred

Comment: I presume you have rebooted the Wildfire also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing The HTC Windows drive , it worked fine!

Answer (score 1):

Use [this](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12141) patched adb version  hope it will work for you, i got something similar with my htc desire and the patch worked for me